# Model not calculating loss during training returning ValueError (Huggingface/BERT)

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I'm unable to properly pass my encoded data (with hidden states) through Trainer via Huggingface. Below is the call to Trainer with arguments and the full traceback. I'm not really sure where to begin with this error as I believe I've satisfied all requirements to pass the encoded data forward unless the inputs passed should include the labels.

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score

def compute_metrics(pred):
    labels = pred.label_ids
    pred = pred.predictions.argmax(-1)
    f1 = f1_score(labels, pred, average="weighted")
    acc = accuracy_score(labels, preds)
    return {"accuracy": acc, "f1": f1}
```

```
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments

batch_size = 10
logging_steps = len(transcripts_encoded["train"]) // batch_size
model_name = f"{model_checkpoint}-finetuned-transcripts"
training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir=model_name,
                                 num_train_epochs=2,
                                 learning_rate=2e-5,
                                 per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
                                 per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
                                 weight_decay=0.01,
                                 evaluation_strategy="epoch",
                                 disable_tqdm=False,
                                 logging_steps=logging_steps,
                                 push_to_hub=False,
                                 log_level="error")

from transformers import Trainer

trainer = Trainer(model=model, args=training_args,
                 compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
                 train_dataset=transcripts_encoded["train"],
                 eval_dataset=transcripts_encoded["valid"],
                 tokenizer=tokenizer)

trainer.train();
```

### `Here is the full traceback:`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-76d295da3120> in <module>
     24                  tokenizer=tokenizer)
     25 
---> 26 trainer.train();

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py in train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   1503             resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,
   1504             trial=trial,
-> 1505             ignore_keys_for_eval=ignore_keys_for_eval,
   1506         )
   1507 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py in _inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   1747                         tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
   1748                 else:
-> 1749                     tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
   1750 
   1751                 if (

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py in training_step(self, model, inputs)
   2506 
   2507         with self.compute_loss_context_manager():
-> 2508             loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)
   2509 
   2510         if self.args.n_gpu > 1:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py in compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs)
   2552             if isinstance(outputs, dict) and "loss" not in outputs:
   2553                 raise ValueError(
-> 2554                     "The model did not return a loss from the inputs, only the following keys: "
   2555                     f"{','.join(outputs.keys())}. For reference, the inputs it received are {','.join(inputs.keys())}."
   2556                 )

ValueError: The model did not return a loss from the inputs, only the following keys: logits. For reference, the inputs it received are input_ids,attention_mask.
```

I was expecting to for it to the training details (f1, loss, accuracy etc). My assumption is that my encoded data with the hidden states is not properly structured for the model to train per the arguments set.

**UPDATED MODEL CODE:
here's where I'm loading and splitting**

```
category_data = load_dataset("csv", data_files="testdatafinal.csv")
category_data = category_data.remove_columns(["someid", "someid", "somedimension"])
category_data = category_data['train']
train_testvalid = category_data.train_test_split(test_size=0.3)
test_valid = train_testvalid['test'].train_test_split(test_size=0.5)
from datasets.dataset_dict import DatasetDict
cd = DatasetDict({
    'train': train_testvalid['train'],
    'test': test_valid['test'],
    'valid': test_valid['train']})
print(cd)

DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['Transcript', 'Primary Label'],
        num_rows: 646
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['Transcript', 'Primary Label'],
        num_rows: 139
    })
    valid: Dataset({
        features: ['Transcript', 'Primary Label'],
        num_rows: 139
    })
})
```

**Here's where I'm grabbing the model checkpoint**

```
model_checkpoint = 'distilbert-base-uncased'
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint).to(device)
```

**Here's where I'm mapping the encoded text**

```
transcripts_encoded_one = transcripts_encoded.set_format("torch",
                              columns=["input_ids", "attention_mask", "Primary Label"])
```

**Here's where i'm extracting hidden states and then mapping as well**

```
def extract_hidden_states(batch):
    #Place model inputs on the GPU/CPU
    inputs = {k:v.to(device) for k, v in batch.items()
              if k in tokenizer.model_input_names}
    #Extract last hidden states
    with torch.no_grad():
        last_hidden_state = model(**inputs).last_hidden_state
    # Return vecot for [CLS] Token
    return {"hidden_state": last_hidden_state[:,0].cpu().numpy()}

transcripts_hidden = transcripts_encoded.map(extract_hidden_states, batched=True)
```

**Calling AutoModel**

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification

num_labels = 10
model =(AutoModelForSequenceClassification
       .from_pretrained(model_checkpoint, num_labels=num_labels)
       .to(device))
```

**Accuracy Metrics**

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score

def compute_metrics(pred):
    labels = pred.label_ids
    pred = pred.predictions.argmax(-1)
    f1 = f1_score(labels, pred, average="weighted")
    acc = accuracy_score(labels, preds)
    return {"accuracy": acc, "f1": f1}
```

**Trainer**

```
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments

batch_size = 10
logging_steps = len(transcripts_encoded_one["train"]) // batch_size
model_name = f"{model_checkpoint}-finetuned-transcripts"
training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir=model_name,
                                 num_train_epochs=2,
                                 learning_rate=2e-5,
                                 per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
                                 per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
                                 weight_decay=0.01,
                                 evaluation_strategy="epoch",
                                 disable_tqdm=False,
                                 logging_steps=logging_steps,
                                 push_to_hub=False,
                                 log_level="error")

from transformers import Trainer

trainer = Trainer(model=model, args=training_args,
                 compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
                 train_dataset=transcripts_encoded_one["train"],
                 eval_dataset=transcripts_encoded_one["valid"],
                 tokenizer=tokenizer)

trainer.train();
```

**I've tried passing "transcripts_encoded(without hidden states) and "transcripts_hidden (with hidden states) as the train and validation splits and both produce the same error**

```
trainer.train_dataset[0]

{'Primary Label': 'cancel',
 'input_ids': tensor([  101,  2047,  3446,  2003,  2205,  6450,  2005,  1996,  2051,  1045,
          2064,  5247,  3752,  4790,  1012,  2009,  2001,  2026,  5165,  2000,
          6509,  2017,  2651,   999,  4067,  2017,  2005,  3967,  2075,  1996,
          2047,  2259,  2335,   999,  2031,  1037,  6919,  2717,  1997,  1996,
          2154,   999,  2994,  3647,  1998,  7965,   999,  2065,  2045,  2003,
          2505,  2842,  2057,  2089,  2022,  2583,  2000,  6509,  2017,  2007,
          3531,  2514,  2489,  2000,  3967,  2149,  2153,  1012,  1045,  2001,
          2074,  2667,  2000, 17542,  2026, 15002,  1012,  2038,  2009,  2042,
         13261,  1029,  7632,  1010,  2045,   999,  1045,  3246,  2017,  1005,
          2128,  2725,  2092,  2651,  1012,  4067,  2017,  2005,  3967,  2075,
           102]),
 'attention_mask': tensor([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1])}
```

Answer (score 2):

If possible, can you add your model code? According to your indicators and description, you should use `BartForSequenceClassification`. If you are using `BartForSequenceClassification`, I think the biggest possibility is that your training dataset has no labels.

```
loss = None
if labels is not None:
    ...
if not return_dict:
    output = (logits,) + outputs[1:]
    return ((loss,) + output) if loss is not None else output

return Seq2SeqSequenceClassifierOutput(
    loss=loss,
    logits=logits,
    past_key_values=outputs.past_key_values,
    decoder_hidden_states=outputs.decoder_hidden_states,
    decoder_attentions=outputs.decoder_attentions,
    cross_attentions=outputs.cross_attentions,
    encoder_last_hidden_state=outputs.encoder_last_hidden_state,
    encoder_hidden_states=outputs.encoder_hidden_states,
    encoder_attentions=outputs.encoder_attentions,
)
```

`modeling_outputs` in `transformers` will drop the key which the value is `None`, then it will rasie `ValueError` that you describe.

**UPDATE**
Thanks for such detailed code. I find out the problem. You should set `TrainingArguments.label_names` to ["Primary Label"] or change `Primary Label` to any label string containing lowercase letters "label" like `Primary label`. for more details, see `transformers.utils.generic.find_labels`. Otherwise it will use the default label name instead of `Primary Label`. Furthermore you must map label to consecutive integers not `cancel` !!

Comment: I've updated the code to show each block. I've also confirmed that both splits (encoded w/out hidden states and encoded w/ hidden states has my label column (no nulls).                                                                                                                                                 print(transcripts_hidden["train"].column_names)
['Transcript', 'Primary Label', 'input_ids', 'attention_mask', 'hidden_state']

Comment: where in my code would I insert the if statement you've provided above. I agree that I'm most likely somehow dropping the labels when passing to the trainer but not sure how. Thanks!

Comment: I inspected whats actually in my training dataset and the labels are there.

Comment: @Wesson Thanks for such detailed code. I find out the problem. You should set `TrainingArguments.label_names` to ["Primary Label"] or change `Primary Label` to any label string containing lowercase letters "label" like `Primary label`. for more details, see `transformers.utils.generic.find_labels`. Otherwise it will use the default label name instead of `Primary Label`. Furthermore you must map label to consecutive integers not `cancel` !!

Comment: Thanks I'll confirm if this ends up working

Answer (score 0):

after trying the solutions you have mentioned and what the Hugging Face documentation indicates, **I FINALLY FIXED THE ERROR (at least for my case)**. The error in question was:

```
ValueError: The model did not return a loss of inputs, only the following keys: last_hidden_state,past_key_values. For reference, the inputs it received are input_ids,attention_mask.
```

The indications and steps taken into account are:

- Rename the labels column as `label`.
- Apply a cast on this column to the ClassLabel type.
- When defining the tokenizer function, specify the hyperparameters `text` and `text_target` (without that the sequence 'labels' is not created in the tokenized dataset) and `padding='max_length'`.
- Tokenize the dataset after the above and then immediately delete the columns corresponding to the original dataset.
- In the TrainingArguments hyperparameters set `remove_unused_columns=False` (default is True and I understand that is why it does not take 'labels' as the inputs received).

**With the above resolved started training. For better reference, I attach the link to the notebook (the comments are in Spanish): https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Rulxn6Io--xkpDgIfXPudU85CQQnF2bp?usp=sharing**

I hope this helps those who have the same problem.

P.D: In the hyperparameters of the tokenizer function I had first set `padding=True` (in addition to `truncation=True`) and that generated me the error:

```
ValueError: Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate truncation and/or padding with 'padding=True' 'truncation=True' to have batched tensors with the same length. Perhaps your features (`labels` in this case) have excessive nesting (inputs type `list` where type `int` is expected)
```

...so I changed it to `padding='max_length'`.